# Marking y value using dotted line in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using *matplotlib.pyplot*.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [i for i in range (1,201)]
y = np.loadtxt('final_fscore.txt', dtype=np.float128)
plt.plot(x, y, lw=2)
plt.show()
```

It looks something like this:
[image: What i have done so far]

I want to mark the first value of x where y has reached the highest ( which is already known, say for x= 23, y= y[23]), like this figure shown below:

[image: What I want to do]

I have been searching this for some time now, with little success. I have tried adding a straight line for now, which is not behaving the desired way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [i for i in range (1,201)]
y = np.loadtxt('final_fscore.txt', dtype=np.float128)

plt.plot(x, y, lw=2)

plt.plot([23,y[23]], [23,0])

plt.show()
```

Resulting graph:

[image: Not what I want]

Note: I want to make the figure like in the second graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what `y[23]` would do here. You would need to find out the maximum value and the index at which this occurs (`np.argmax`). You may then use this to plot a 3 point line with those coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(9)

x = np.arange(200)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(200))
plt.plot(x, y, lw=2)

amax = np.argmax(y)
xlim,ylim = plt.xlim(), plt.ylim()
plt.plot([x[amax], x[amax], xlim[0]], [xlim[0], y[amax], y[amax]],
          linestyle="--")
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.ylim(ylim)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the ambiguity regarding y[23]. Here, I assumed that the highest value of y is at x = 23, so in this case the highest value of y must be y[23].

Comment: Ah, ok, that is ambiguous with python's list index notation where `y[23]` would be the 24th value in `y`.

Comment: Is there any way to also display the values? (0.87 and 320 in the second graph)